# How to solve $T(n)= 4T(\sqrt n) +\log^2n$?

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

Consider the recurrence
$$T(n)= 4T(\sqrt n) + \log^2n. $$
 I am not able to solve this recurrence, since it involves a square root. Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 8):

Let $S(n) = T(2^n)$. Then
$$
S(n) = T(2^n) = 4T(2^{n/2}) + n^2 = 4S(n/2) + n^2.
$$
You can solve this recurrence using the master theorem, and then use $T(n) = S(\log n)$ to obtain a solution for the original recurrence.