# How to solve $T(n)=4T(\sqrt{n}/3)+(\log n)^2$ with the master theorem?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

Can somebody help me with this recurrence please?

$T(n)=4T(\sqrt{n}/3)+(\log n)^2$

Comment: This not exactly the same, but maybe [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118210/how-to-solve-tn-4t-sqrt-n-log2n) can help you?

Comment: @Nathaniel yes. i saw that. but this one is so difficult to solve. just because of that division by 3.

Answer (score 3):

The division by 3 makes the task a little non-trivial, but you can still figure out how to proceed in the manner proposed by the answer suggested by Nathaniel in the comments.

Let $n = 3^{2^k-2}$ and you can modify the recurrence equation as
$$T(n) = 4T\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}\right) + (\log_3{2})^2.(\log_3n)^2$$

However, this modification will only bring a change of constant in your final solution. So we can safely assume that the original equation had the base of the logarithm as 3.

You have that $k = \log_2(\log_3n+2)$, and you can substitute this at the end to find your answer.

Comment: thanks. i tried to solve this by your solution but i guess somehow its not possible to get rid of that division by 3 to be able to solve this by master theorem. right??

Comment: @maryamghanbari You need just to expand the recurrence a little bit based on the introduced substitution.

Comment: @maryamghanbari also if you would like to know how I came up with that substitution, I tried to find a sequence {$a_i$} such that  $a_{i+1}=\frac{\sqrt{a_i}}{3}$ which is $a_i = 3^2a_{i+1}^2$. You can guess the rest.

Comment: @bigbang right. i get it now. thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

**Master Theorem** is for **Dividing** and **Subtracting** Function.
The Master Theorem at it's core **don't discuss Square Root Function.**

Although, some Manipulations can be done.

But for the sake of simplicity, solving by **Substitution Method**

**Given**,

$T(n)=4T\bigg(\frac{\sqrt n}{3}\bigg) + (\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2}}{3}\bigg) + (\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4\bigg(4T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/4}}{3}\bigg) + (\log(n^{1/2}))^2\bigg)+(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4^2T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2^2}}{3}\bigg) + 4(\log(n^{1/2}))^2+(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4^2T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2^2}}{3}\bigg) + (2\log(n^{1/2}))^2+(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4^2T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2^2}}{3}\bigg) + (\log(n))^2+(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4^2T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2^2}}{3}\bigg) + 2(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4^2\bigg(4T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2^3}}{3}\bigg) + (\log(n^{1/2^2}))^2\bigg)+2(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4^3T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2^3}}{3}\bigg) + 4^2(\log(n^{1/2^2}))^2+2(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4^3T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2^3}}{3}\bigg) + {2^2}^2(\log(n^{1/2^2}))^2+2(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4^3T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2^3}}{3}\bigg) + ({2^2}\log(n^{1/2^2}))^2+2(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4^3T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2^3}}{3}\bigg) + (\log(n))^2+2(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=4^3T\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2^3}}{3}\bigg) + 3(\log(n))^2$

Therefore, for **k iterations**

### $$T(n)=4^kT\bigg(\frac{n^{1/2^k}}{3}\bigg) + k(\log(n))^2$$

Now, **Assuming** $T(1)=1$

Therefore, put $$\frac{n^{1/2^k}}{3}=1$$

$$n^{1/2^k}  =  3$$

$$\frac{1}{2^k}log_3n  =  1$$

$${2^k}  =  log_3n$$
$$k  =  log_2(log_3n)$$

Thus,

### $$T(n)=4^{log_2(log_3n)}T(1) + {log_2(log_3n)}(\log(n))^2$$

Solving Further,

$T(n)=2^{2log_2(log_3n)} + {log_2(log_3n)}.(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=2^{log_2(log_3n)^2} + {log_2(log_3n)}.(\log(n))^2$

$T(n)=(log_3n)^2 + {log_2(log_3n)}.(\log(n))^2$

Since, we don't know **base of logarithm** given in **Recurrence Relation**, and also since base don't matter on applying **Base Change Formula**

$T(n)=(\log(n))^2 + {log(logn)}.(\log(n))^2$

### **Therefore, $T(n)$ is $O\bigg((log(logn)). (log n)^2\bigg)$**

Comment: Readers, if you found any Mathematical Calculation Error, then please post comment on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Define S(n) = T(2^n), write down a recursion formula for S, solve it using the master theorem, and then let T(m) = S(log m).

Or calculate T(n) for n = 3^0, 3^2, 3^6, 3^14, 3^30, 3^62 etc. without the master theorem, guess a formula for T(3^(2^k-2), and prove it.

Let D  log 3.

If T(1) = c, then T(9) = 4T(1) + (log 9)^2  = 4c + 4D^2.

T(3^6) = 4T(9) + 36D^2 = 16c + 52D^2.

T(3^14) = 4T(3^6) + 196D^2 = 64c + 404D^2.

T(3^30) = 4T(3^14) + 900D^2 = 256c + 2516D^4

Etc.